# My draggable object wen i start to drag is become invisible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I build  a brand new cards game every thing is work with out any errors ,
But wen i start to drag my object in this case is a card in to the drop zone my card is not visible for some reason , i am not sure but i thing they out of screen range or some thing like that i can not find the way to correct this , i try to debug but there is no error on it so i am not able to find the way to solve this.
This is my code for the draggable object

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {

public Transform parentToReturnTo = null;
public Transform placeholderParent = null;

GameObject placeholder = null;

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
    Debug.Log ("OnBeginDrag");

    placeholder = new GameObject();
    placeholder.transform.SetParent( this.transform.parent );
    LayoutElement le = placeholder.AddComponent<LayoutElement>();
    le.preferredWidth = this.GetComponent<LayoutElement>().preferredWidth;
    le.preferredHeight = this.GetComponent<LayoutElement>().preferredHeight;
    le.flexibleWidth = 0;
    le.flexibleHeight = 0;

    placeholder.transform.SetSiblingIndex( this.transform.GetSiblingIndex() );

    parentToReturnTo = this.transform.parent;
    placeholderParent = parentToReturnTo;
    this.transform.SetParent( this.transform.parent.parent );

    GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
    //Debug.Log ("OnDrag");

    this.transform.position = eventData.position;

    if(placeholder.transform.parent != placeholderParent)
        placeholder.transform.SetParent(placeholderParent);

    int newSiblingIndex = placeholderParent.childCount;

    for(int i=0; i < placeholderParent.childCount; i++) {
        if(this.transform.position.x < placeholderParent.GetChild(i).position.x) {

            newSiblingIndex = i;

            if(placeholder.transform.GetSiblingIndex() < newSiblingIndex)
                newSiblingIndex--;

            break;
        }
    }

    placeholder.transform.SetSiblingIndex(newSiblingIndex);

}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
    Debug.Log ("OnEndDrag");
    this.transform.SetParent( parentToReturnTo );
    this.transform.SetSiblingIndex( placeholder.transform.GetSiblingIndex() );
    GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;

    Destroy(placeholder);
}


}
```

Comment: In UI the order of siblings define there rendering order ... could changing the SiblingIndex be a problem?

Comment: @derHugo Tank you to replay is there any way i can make it work properlly because  i can not make my card bee in the mouse position wen i start to drag

Comment: @derHugo and yes maybe change that part will solve the problem

Comment: @derHugo can you pls show me the wright way to do it pls